# Evaluate an integral by changing to cylindrical coordinates

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, differential-geometry

I have to evaluate the following integral by changing to cylindrical coordinates.
Should I just substitute all the $x,y,z$ to cylindrical coordinates?

$\int_{-2}^2\int_{-\sqrt{4-y^2}}^\sqrt{4-y^2}\int_\sqrt{x^2+y^2}^2 xzdzdxdy$

Comment: So first before you do the change in coordinates, you must understand the region of space you have at hand. You have the following inequations: $ -2\leq y\leq 2$, $-\sqrt{4-y^2}\leq x\leq \sqrt{4-y^2}$ and finally $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\leq z\leq 2$. What type of region of the plane do the 1st 2 inequations describe? Once this is described you can switch to cylindrical coordinates because this will let you know the ranges for $\theta$, $r$ and $z$.

Answer (score 2):

The region  $(x,y,z) :-2 \leq y \leq 2, -\sqrt{4-y^2} \leq x \leq \sqrt{4-y^2}, \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \leq z \leq 2$ is the region above the cone $ z = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ and below the plane $z = 2$. In polar coordinates, this region is $(r, \theta, z): 0 \leq r \leq 2, 0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi, r \leq z \leq 2$. If $I$ is the value of the integral,

$$\begin{align}
I &= \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^2 \int_r^2 z \cdot \underbrace{r \cos \theta}_{x} \,dz \,r \, dr \,d\theta \\
&= \left[ \int_0^{2\pi} \cos \theta \,d\theta \right] \cdot \left[ \int_0^2 \int_r^2 r^2 z \,dz  \,dr \right] \\
&= \left[ \sin \theta \right]_0^{2\pi} \cdot \left[ \int_0^2 \int_r^2 r^2 z \,dz  \,dr \right] \\
&= 0
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's first evaluate the integral as is:

$$\begin{align}I &= \int_{-2}^2 dy \, \int_{-\sqrt{4-y^2}}^{\sqrt{4-y^2}} dx  \, x \, \int_{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}^2 dz \, z\\ &= \int_{-2}^2 dy \, \int_{-\sqrt{4-y^2}}^{\sqrt{4-y^2}} dx  \, x \,\left (2 - x^2-y^2 \right )\\ &= 0 \end{align} $$

because we are integrating an odd function over a symmetric interval.  Now let's try this in polar coordinates:

$$\begin{align}I &= \underbrace{\int_{0}^{2 \pi} d\theta \, \cos{\theta}}_{\text{=0}} \, \int_{0}^{2} dr  \, r^2 \, \int_{r}^2 dz \, z = 0 \end{align} $$

Comment: Is it true that $\int_0^2 \int_r^2 r^2 z \,dz  \,dr =  \int_0^2 \,dr \, r^2 \int_r^2 \,dz \,z$?. $r$ is one of the integration limits for the integral with respect to $z$, so I don't think that's true.

Comment: @SplitInfinity: I use the differential-first notation to eliminate confusion of the kind you are introducing.  You read right to left, so, yeah, this is correct.

Comment: Oh...I've never seen differential-first notation before, haha. You learn something new everyday!